# Problem with Erfi in Integrate function

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a very simple integral of the form

```
Integrate[(E^-(x - 1)^2 (x - 1) + E^-(x + 1)^2 (x + 1))/ x, {x, 0, 
  Infinity}]
```

Numerically, this gives the correct answer $-0.134988$. However, doing this using Integrate function gives incorrect answer of $\sqrt{\pi }+\frac{i \pi }{e}$. Clearly by inspecting the plot, this is real. At first, I thought it is simply a funny way of how Infinity behaves, but I found something funny may instead lie in Erfi($z$), because when I instead perform a slightly deformed analytic integral

```
Limit[Integrate[(E^-(-1 + x)^2 (-1 + x) + E^-(1 + x)^2 (1 + x))/
  x^a, {x, 0, Infinity}], a -> 1]
```

This gives the correct *analytic* answer $\sqrt{\pi}-\frac{\pi\text{Erfi}(1)}{e}$. Clearly, it is the singular part $\frac{e^{-(x\pm 1)^2}}{x}$ which caused problems, and performing this limit $a\to 1$ has an exact expression in hypergeometric series which tends to $\text{Erfi}(1)$. To put it another way, the original integral has somehow computed $\text{Erfi}(-i\infty)=-i$ instead of $\text{Erfi}(1)$.

Is this purely a software problem (hence to be reported to Mathematica), or is there a fundamental and practical reason behind how one should do this analytically? For example, is it the case that whenever possible, I should perform this sort of extension to $x^a$ and take limit?

Comment: At least since version 7.

Comment: @user64494 do you mean since version 7 it is a problem? Is there something concrete to be said about the problem?

Comment: This lasts since version 7.

Comment: I'd report it to WR as a bug.